# Step down dc voltage

Tags: signal-processing

One sensor output gives voltage range within 5mv to 50v..I need to give this to an adc (analog to digital converter )..however the adc available is upto 10v.i need to stepdown hight voltage to low voltage(50v to 10V, 25V to 5V like this linear) to give it within adc input range..Any standard circuitry for this to reduce this high voltage dc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple voltage divider. Op amp decreases divider's output resistance. The x value at resistors depends on your sensor output resistance and its current efficiency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5XgIX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>